Adiabatic evolution vs QAOA
Attempting to understand some basics here before
developing an quantum algorithm.
Would of you be able to help clarify the
following definitions I attempted to construct
which compare the two approaches:

From what I gather, an adiabatic evolution, the
Total Energy State (Hamiltonian) is varied over time
against constant model (system) parameter values. This
Hamiltonian is reduced gradually until the ground state is optimal.

Compared to, QAOA uses a parameterized circuit model,
where parameters (i.e., entanglements, rotations) are changed,
outputs are measured, and the optimal objective function
solution is used to determine the best parameter combination.


In Qiskit, how would the results be expressed? (i.e., what units)
How does one evaluate which one is optimal when compared between
the two approaches?
